# Orthographic rendering with modern OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, matrix, rendering, lwjgl

Hi so I am trying to render a quad using a orthographic projection matrix. When I load the matrix into the shader without transposing it nothing shows up on the screen however if I do transpose it I get a diagonal line that shows up on the screen instead of a quad (See picture below) (a quad renders fine when not multiplying the orthographic matrix). I have tried rotating the object, moving it back and forth and tried a different method of creating a orthographic matrix and nothing seams to be working. I am also not doing any culling. Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this? Also should I be transposing all the matrices I pass into the shader? I have heard multiple different answers regarding that.

My goal is to create a orthographic projection with modern OpenGL and not use any immediate mode techniques.

Current Result:
[image]

Matrix output:
I assume the problem has to do with the result of the matrix but I have done the calculations and this seams correct?

```
0.0015625 0.0 0.0 -1.0
0.0 -0.0027777778 0.0 1.0
0.0 0.0 -1.0 -0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 orthographicMatrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = orthographicMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position.xy, 0, 1.0);
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
}
```

Matrix Creation:

```
orthographicMatrix = Maths.createOrthoProjectionMatrix(0f, (float) Display.getWidth(), 0f, (float) Display.getHeight(), -1.0f, 1.0f);

public static Matrix4f createOrthoProjectionMatrix(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float near, float far) {
    Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f();

    m.m00 = 2.0f / (right - left);
    m.m01 = 0.0f;
    m.m02 = 0.0f;
    m.m03 = 0.0f;

    m.m10 = 0.0f;
    m.m11 = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
    m.m12 = 0.0f;
    m.m13 = 0.0f;

    m.m20 = 0.0f;
    m.m21 = 0.0f;
    m.m22 = -2.0f / (far - near);
    m.m23 = 0.0f;

    m.m30 = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    m.m31 = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    m.m32 = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    m.m33 = 1.0f;

    return m;
}
```

Rendering Code:

```
public void render(Entity entity, StaticShader shader) {
    TexturedModel texturedModel = entity.getTexturedModel();
    RawModel model = texturedModel.getRawModel();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
    shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturedModel.getTexture().getTextureID());
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Transformation Matrix:

```
public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector2f translation, float rx, float ry, float rz, float scale) {
    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
    matrix.setIdentity();
    Matrix4f.translate(translation, matrix, matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), matrix, matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), matrix, matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), matrix, matrix);
    Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale, scale, 1), matrix, matrix);
    return matrix;
}
```

Vertices, Indices and Texture Coords of quad:

```
public static final float[] BOX_VERTICES = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f,
};

public static final int[] BOX_INDICES = {
        0, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2
};

public static final float[] BOX_TEXTURE_COORDS = {
        0, 0,
        0, 1,
        1, 1,
        1, 0
};
```

VAO and VBO creation:

```
public RawModel loadToVAO(float[] positions, float[] textureCoords, int[] indices) {
    int vaoID = createVAO();
    bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
    storeDataInAttributeList(0, positions);
    storeDataInAttributeList(1, textureCoords);
    unbindVAO();
    return new RawModel(vaoID, indices.length);
}

private int createVAO() {
    int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    vaos.add(vaoID);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    return vaoID;
}

private void storeDataInAttributeList(int attributeNumber, float[] data) {
    int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices) {
    int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    IntBuffer buffer = storeDataInIntBuffer(indices);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

private IntBuffer storeDataInIntBuffer(int[] data) {
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}

private FloatBuffer storeDataInFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}

private void unbindVAO() {
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Shader Class:

```
public class StaticShader extends ShaderProgram {

    private int location_transformationMatrix;
    private int location_orthographicMatrix;

    public StaticShader() {
        super("src/com/robert/game/shaders/staticVertexShader.glsl", "src/com/robert/game/shaders/staticFragmentShader.glsl");
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindAttributes() {
        super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
        super.bindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
    }

    @Override
    protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
        location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
        location_orthographicMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("orthographicMatrix");
    }

    public void loadTransformationMatrix(Matrix4f matrix) {
        super.loadMatrix(location_transformationMatrix, matrix);
    }

    public void loadOrthographicMatrix(Matrix4f matrix) {
        super.loadMatrix(location_orthographicMatrix, matrix);
    }
}
```

Shader Load Matrix:
The transpose parameter was originally false which resulted in nothing being shown on the screen.

```
private static FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

protected void loadMatrix(int location, Matrix4f matrix) {
    matrix.store(matrixBuffer);
    matrixBuffer.flip();
    GL20.glUniformMatrix4(location, true, matrixBuffer);
}

public Renderer(StaticShader shader) {
    orthographicMatrix = Maths.createOrthoProjectionMatrix(0f, (float) Display.getWidth(), 0f, (float) Display.getHeight(), -1.0f, 1.0f);
    System.out.println(orthographicMatrix);
    shader.start();
    shader.loadOrthographicMatrix(orthographicMatrix);
    shader.stop();
}
```

Comment: The ortho matrix looks fine.  The problem is likely to be in code you don't show, i.e. how you're configuring your vertex buffers.

Comment: ... and what `transformationMatrix` do you use?

Comment: I would suggest to try building ortho matrix with a lib like glm to make sure you have no errors there.Then check your geometry data.The green line looks line a line drawn. Do you draw lines in some place? Can you show your client side rendering code?

Comment: I added the code you guys requested. However I don't think it would have anything to do with the transformation matrix or how I create the vertex buffers due to the fact that it works file without multiplying in the orthographic matrix. (Of course I could be wrong). No I do not draw lines any where that line seams to be the quad.

Comment: Where do you pass `orthographicMatrix` to the shader?

Comment: There you go I edited the post to include that code.

Comment: I don't see it in the render code (as you do for `transformationMatrix`), just in the shader class.

Comment: Sorry my bad I just added onto the Shader load matrix code. I do it in the constructor of the class as I don't think it needs to be loaded up every time you render something because it only changes if you change the screen size.

Comment: I give up. There are many things not shown. Your ortho only exposes [0-w, 0-h] range of world coordinates, but your vertices are [-0.5 to 0.5]. This "half-cut" can be overloaded by translations, but you don't expose them, only their methods. I advice working with a simple code, to get trained with transformations, and later build more complex classes.

Comment: Is the shader bound when you upload the orthographic and transformation matrices?  Also, does your shader work when you set them to the identity matrix by default in the shader?

Comment: Yes the shader is bound when uploading the orthographic matrix. And it does work when the orthographic matrix is set to identity matrix. The transformation matrix has been working regardless so I do not think it has anything to do with the transformation matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rabbid76 I ended up changing the vertices slightly as well as the scale and position. Then changed the transpose to false and ended up getting it working properly.